# Sublime Text и Github: как загрузить с гита файл?

Tags: framework, git, github

Друзья, подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли осуществить задуманное, и, если можно, то как?
Суть вопроса проста: хочу установить для Slim Framework [расширение Slim-Extras/HttpBasicAuth](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras/tree/master/Middleware). Как я понимаю из описания, нужный файл должен лежать в папке Middleware. Конечно, я могу ручками скачать и положить его туда, но может мне гит поможет это сделать способом попроще?

- В описании расширения путь указан как \Slim\Extras\Middleware\, но в последней версии слима нет папки Extras. Наверное, описание старое?

Comment: Поставьте через комопзер, как зависимость.

Comment: @hcuser, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Проще? Навряд ли...

Вот есть решенеие на so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125476/git-retrieve-a-single-file-from-a-repository

Но оно меня со-о-овсем не радует. :)

Comment: Хм, ну хорошо, а если целиком папку скачать, — как это можно сделать?

Comment: Эм, так же? Просто укажите адрес до директории и все.

Почитайте про git-archive.

Comment: Спасибо, друг, а то я в этом деле новичок.